# Programmatically Add Exception to windows vista firewall

Tags: windows, exception, firewall

Is there any way to programmatically add an .exe file to the exception list for the Windows Vista firewall to allow it to run normally? I'm using VC++.

Comment: Why do you want this? Exception list in firewall should be modified only with user acknowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - if you take a look at the WindowsFirewallAddApp method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364726(VS.85).aspx), it should give you some ideas how to do it.

Comment: Vista Firewall, one and only firewall in the world that can be disabled programatically by any program.

Comment: Any program. If it has admin privileges. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff956123%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Link to the MSDN documentation of the API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366319(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for certain about the Vista firewall, but I would defeinitely excpect that it is a violation of the security of any computer to allow programmatic access to firewall exception lists.  I would be very surprised if Windows allowed arbitrary code to fiddle with the Firewall in this way.

The user sitting in front of the computer, or a network administrator setting network wide security policies would be the only two who should be able to do this.  Notice that they are both actual people doing the process interactively.

Comment: Then be very surprised. :-) It is absolutely possible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366319(v=vs.85).aspx