# Windows firewall rule for XP

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-7, windows-firewall

How to programmatically add an application or port to Windows Firewall on Windows XP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically Add Exception to windows vista firewall .](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409896/programatically-add-exception-to-windows-vista-firewall)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add to Firewall Exception list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384718/add-to-firewall-exception-list)

Comment: This answer only works in xp. edited title since OP accepted this and its useful info, therefore not a dupe since the duplicate works in win7 and vista only.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this code extracted from our open source [SQlite3UI.pas](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SQLite3/SQLite3UI.pas) unit:

```
function GetXPFirewall(var fwMgr, profile: OleVariant): boolean;
begin
  Result := (Win32Platform=VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) and
    (Win32MajorVersion>5) or ((Win32MajorVersion=5) and (Win32MinorVersion>0));
  if result then // need Windows XP at least
  try 
    fwMgr := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwMgr');
    profile := fwMgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      result := false;
  end;
end;

const
  NET_FW_PROFILE_DOMAIN = 0;
  NET_FW_PROFILE_STANDARD = 1;
  NET_FW_IP_VERSION_ANY = 2;
  NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_UDP = 17;
  NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP = 6;
  NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL = 0;
  NET_FW_SCOPE_LOCAL_SUBNET = 1;

procedure AddApplicationToXPFirewall(const EntryName, ApplicationPathAndExe: string);
var fwMgr, profile, app: OleVariant;
begin
  if GetXPFirewall(fwMgr,profile) then
  try
    if profile.FirewallEnabled then begin
      app := CreateOLEObject('HNetCfg.FwAuthorizedApplication');
      try
        app.ProcessImageFileName := ApplicationPathAndExe;
        app.Name := EntryName;
        app.Scope := NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL;
        app.IpVersion := NET_FW_IP_VERSION_ANY;
        app.Enabled :=true;
        profile.AuthorizedApplications.Add(app);
      finally
        app := varNull;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    profile := varNull;
    fwMgr := varNull;
  end;
end;

procedure AddPortToXPFirewall(const EntryName: string; PortNumber: cardinal);
var fwMgr, profile, port: OleVariant;
begin
  if GetXPFirewall(fwMgr,profile) then
  try
    if profile.FirewallEnabled then begin
      port := CreateOLEObject('HNetCfg.FWOpenPort');
      port.Name := EntryName;
      port.Protocol := NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
      port.Port := PortNumber;
      port.Scope := NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL;
      port.Enabled := true;
      profile.GloballyOpenPorts.Add(port);
    end;
  finally
    port := varNull;
    profile := varNull;
    fwMgr := varNull;
  end;
end;
```

It will allow you to add an application or a port to the XP firewall.
Should work from Delphi 6 up to XE.

Comment: I've updated the source of the unit to work on XP, Vista and Seven, either for an application, either for a port. See http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=4652#p4652

Answer (score 6):

Scripting the Windows Firewall is possible, see [Scripting the Windows Firewall](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee692840%28en-us%29.aspx#EFAA)

And code examples for example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/WinXPSP2Firewall.aspx)

Comment: Delphi 7 supports COM based scripting

Comment: In this case you should try to import the type library, see my link, it mentions that the type library DLL file `is usually located in "C:\Windows\System32\hnetcfg.dll"` (this article is about XP, I checked in Windows 7 and a file with this name is there)

Comment: To import it try `tlibimp -P c:\windows\system32\hnetcfg.dll` - however looking at its content I am not sure if this is the correct file

Comment: Also can use late binding as in the question [Add to Firewall Exception list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384718/add-to-firewall-exception-list)

Comment: Hi Michael, due to a new answer I stumbled upon this thread. Your answer according to the current rules to link only to reply, maybe you want to improve it.